# Дубль главной страницы сайта site.ru/ и site.ru

Tags: .htaccess, site

При сканирования сайта на сервисе pr-cy показывает дубль главной страницы ( title и description ).

Comment: И? Где ваш htaccess?

Comment: @Dmitry Там 720строк и 28000 символов.

Comment: [Ссылка на htaccess  в формате txt] https://dropmefiles.com/0qhhw